# Autofac - Register Generic Type with lambda expression

Tags: generics, entity-framework-6, autofac

I am trying to register IDbSet as a dependency for my logic classes.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
    builder.Register(c => 
    {
        var context = myContainer.Resolve<MyDbContext>();
        return context.Set<T>();// Problem Here 
    }).As(typeof(System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<>));
```

Or suggest an alternate way to access my DbSets without giving my logic classes an entire instance of MyDBContext.

Comment: Have you seen [this example of logging integration](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) that does something similar using a module?